# How to restart stuck Java program?

Tags: java

My program is fairly large, and because it tends to carry out processes randomly, at times it gets stuck and loops forever. If I were to forcefully stop and restart the program manually, usually (around 85%) of the time, the program completes all commands  and terminates.

Is there a way to make a Java program restart itself after say 20 seconds, if it gets stuck? I tried using the system time to solve the issue, but the problem with this is that if my program gets stuck in a for loop, it does not update the system time until the next iteration.

Comment: Restarting program when it contains such serious issue will not solve the problem. Find the root cause.

Comment: Your best option is to find the cause of it. I suggest adding some debug messages and when it gets stuck, look at the last debug message and that should give you an idea where it's failing. Adding system-state parameters might pinpoint the exact problem

Comment: (A +1 because I think that the current answers and comments are very relevant and should have a larger audience.)

Comment: Another strategy for figuring out the issue is to start writing unit tests. It's especially important when your project gets fairly large. You'll appreciate having tests that express your intentions when you put the project down for awhile and try to pick it back up and figure out why you did some things the way you did.

Comment: Another approach is to debug your program using a debugger.  If it takes on 20 seconds, all you need do is pause the program after this time and see where and why its stuck in a loop.

Comment: Besides the advice to find the cause for problem (which is the best advice in your case, IMHO) - What would you do if the program just lags a bit because of high system load? How should any other program (the JVM or other tools) know whether the Java program is stuck in an endless loop or if it just processes data normally or waits for other resources? - Ok, you could do that, but would you be able to tell in every case? If you can't (and just have to "assume" things), how should any tool do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that solving this problem would mean solving the Halting problem, we can be fairly sure that the whole approach is doomed ;)

You could obviously use timers to kill the program after some specified time and whatnot, but really - find the bugs in your program.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't the right way to approach this problem!  You need to figure out why your program is getting stuck in an infinite loop, and then fix it.  "Okay let's try this again" is not the right way to solve a bug - you have no idea what other effects this bug could be having.  You might very well be getting incorrect output as well.  Debug the program, don't work around the flaw.

You could use some external program that launches the java program and kills it after 20 seconds when it gets stuck, and then launches it again, but again, that is not the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your program shouldn't stuck and loops forever, repair this. But if this isn't possible and you still want "restart" program after forever-loop I propose you such solution:

Create main program which will be director. The director will be create thread. The thread will be doing main algorithm which can take a lot of time. The director will be waiting some time which will be final parameter. This parameter help to director recognises if the thread is in forever loop (it takes too long time). When forever-loop will be recognize, it'll terminate the thread and start new one (restart).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ExecutorServices to get a mechanism that allows you to invoke a piece of code and receive a timeout if it doesn't finish within the expected time.  You can then act upon as you see fit.

Another nice tool is to use jvisualvm in the JDK to attach to the program when looping.  You can then ask for a thread dump and use it to figure out what it is doing.